# How to save results from mySQL database into a file or variable in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, inheritance

I have a little app which takes users coordinates from client and searches for a nearest location in my mySQL database. I need to grab the results from my database and save them to a file or assign these results to a variable.
What do I need to add to a code below to achieve it?

```
import mysql.connector


mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT dbx, dby, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (dbx - userx), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (usery - dby) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 125 ORDER BY distance;")

mydb.commit()
```

`dbx` and `dby` are longitude and latitude parameters from the points which are stored in database
`userx` and `usery` are longitude and latitude parameters taken from the client-side.

Comment: *How to save results from mySQL database into a file* Execute `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the result of your query and save it to a variable, with the following:

```
res=mycursor.execute("SELECT dbx, dby, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (dbx - userx), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (usery - dby) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 125 ORDER BY distance;").fetcall()
```

res will be a list of tuples eg `[(0.53, 75.32, 2000), (0.55, 62.75, 3000)]`

You can now save it to txt file with the following:

```
with open('res.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([(str(i)+'\n') for i in res])
```

You can also save it as csv, as json, or any other format you want, but txt in your case will be fine

Answer (score 2):

The query results can be placed into the file `/tmp/some_filename.txt` using the query:

```
SELECT dbx, dby, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (dbx - userx), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (usery - dby) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 125 ORDER BY distance
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/some_filename.txt'
```

If you want to use a separator and quote character, add this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

If you want to add line terminator for output file:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```